# Find value of t then the series is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { n ^ { 3 n } } { ( n + 2 ) ^ { 2 n + t } ( n + t ) ^ { n + 2 t } }$$
I use the ratio test, than I saw the series failed.
Right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using root test, I find:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac { n ^ { 3 n } } { ( n + 2 ) ^ { 2 n + t } ( n + t ) ^ { n + 2 t } }} = \frac { n^3 } { ( n + 2 ) ^ { 2 + t/n } ( n + t ) ^ { 1 + 2 t/n } } = \frac { 1 } { n^{3t/n}\ ( 1 + 2/n ) ^ { 2 + t/n } ( 1 + t/n ) ^ { 1 + 2 t/n } } \to 1$$

therefore the root test is inconclusive and, for a well-known theorem, the ratio test also has to be inconclusive.

On the other hand, I also find:

$$\frac { n ^ { 3 n } } { ( n + 2 ) ^ { 2 n + t } ( n + t ) ^ { n + 2 t } } = \frac { n ^ { 3 n } } { n^{3n+3t} ( 1 + 2/n ) ^ { 2 n + t } ( 1 + t/n ) ^ { n + 2 t } } = \frac { 1 } {n^{3t} ( 1 + 2/n ) ^ { 2 n } (1+2/n)^{ t } ( 1 + t/n ) ^ { n } (1+t/n)^{2 t } } \approx \frac{1}{e^{4+t}\ n^{3t}}$$

therefore your series converges for $3t >1$ by *limit comparison test* (or something like that).